# Which step assumes non-injective function? (Sets, Functions)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

This post is based on a common exercise, but I am asking a question beyond that exercise.

---

**Context**

The exercise:

> Let $A$, $B$ be two subsets of a set $X$, and let $f:X \to Y$ be a
> function. Show that $f(A \cap B) \subseteq f(A) \cap f(B)$.

My solution is very similar to the many posted online.

> We need to show that if $y \in f(A \cap B)$ then $y \in f(A) \cap f(B)$.
>
> If $y \in f(A \cap B)$ then there exists an $x \in (A \cap B)$ such
> that $f(x) = y$.
>
> Now,
>
> $$x \in (A \cap B) \iff (x \in A) \land (x \in B) \tag{i}$$
>
> So,
>
> $$ y = f(x) \in f(A \cap B) \implies (y \in f(A)) \land (y \in f(B)) \tag{ii}$$
>
> Thus, we have shown that if $y \in f(A \cap B)$ then $y \in f(A) \cap f(B)$.
>
> This is equivalent to $f(A \cap B) \subseteq f(A) \cap f(B)$. $\square$

---

**My Question**

For the two sets to be equal, $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$, my thinking is that the function $f$ needs to be injective.

Looking back at the solution, at line (i), the implication is bi-directional, but at line (ii) it is a one-way implication.

If we were able to preserve that bi-directional implication at line (ii) then we could eventually show the two sets are the same.

However there is a gap in my knowledge or thinking. I can't see why line (ii) is a one-way implication. If someone can explain this, that would help me see more clearly whether an injective function preserves the $\iff$ at line (ii).

Comment: Your proof of $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$ is fine. Another way is stating that $A\cap B\subseteq A$ implies directly that $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)$. Similarly we also have $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(B)$ and combining both results we conclude that $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$ q.e.d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so if $f$ is injective and $y\in f(A)\cap f(B)$, then there exist $a\in A$, $b\in B$ with $y = f(a)$ and $y = f(b)$. Since $f$ is injective, $y=f(a)=f(b)$ implies that $a=b$. In particular, $a=b\in A\cap B$, so $y\in f(A\cap B)$.

**Edit:** The crucial step here is that without injectivity, you cannot find an element in $A\cap B$; you just have one in $A$ and one in $B$ which map to $y$. Injectivity allows you to conclude that they're the same, hence in both sets.

Answer (score 1):

If you want $f:X\to Y$ to be a function that satisfies $f(A)\cap f(B)\subseteq f(A\cap B)$ (or equivalently $f(A)\cap f(B)=f(A\cap B)$) for *every* pair of subsets $A,B$ then injectivity is indeed necessary.

This becomes evident if we consider singleton sets $\{a\},\{b\}$.

If in that case $a\neq b$ then we arrive at:$$f(\{a\})\cap f(\{b\})\subseteq f(\{a\}\cap\{b\})=f(\varnothing)=\varnothing$$
which is the same statement as $f(a)\neq f(b)$.

Let me mention though that for a function $f$ that is not injective it is quite well possible that subsets $A,B$ *exist* such that $f(A)\cap f(B)=f(A\cap B)$.

If for instance $f$ is a constant function then this equality is true whenever $A\cap B\neq\varnothing$.

Comment: Thanks @drhab this is very helpful, especially with the example of singletons, and also the clarification that equality is possible without $f$ injective for some $f$.

Comment: Glad to help. You are very welcome.